# How to convert FOR to WHILE?

Tags: java, processing

I just want to convert this "for-loop" to a "while-loop"?

I tried all, but nothing works.

For Loop:

```
for(int k = 3; k > 0; k--)
{
     if(k % 2 == 0)
         continue;
     println(k);
}
```

I tried:

```
int k = 3;
while(k > 0)
{
    if (k % 2 == 0){
        continue;
    }
    k--;
    println(k);
}
```

But the console says different values? Can you pls help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to change the control variable `k` at the end of the loop and right before the `continue` statement. right before the the condition expression of the loop is evaluated again:

```java
int k = 3;
while(k > 0)
{
    if (k % 2 == 0) {
        k --;      // <--- add
        continue; 
    }

    // k--;          <--- remove
    println(k);

    k --;         // <--- add
}
```

Note, a `for` loop consist of a  *init-statement*, a *condition expression* and an *iteration_expression*.
If a `for` loop statement has to be expressed as a `while` loop statement, then the *init-statement* has to be done before the loop, the *condition expression* can be reused for the condition in the `while` loop and the *iteration expression* has to be done last in the `while` loop. Further the *iteration expression* expression has to be done before every `continue` statement in the `while` loop.

If the `continue` statement is eliminated, the it is sufficient to do the *iteration expression* once at the end of the loop:

```java
int k = 3;
while(k > 0)
{
    if (k % 2 != 0) {
        println(k);
    }
    k --;
}
```